# Problems by using .map() function for json/array using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am building a React-App and I hae a problem working with `json/array` an the `.map()-function`.
My serverside json object looks like :

```
let jsonlist = [
    {
        Title: "first title",
        Listofitems: ["Item 01", "Item 02", "Item 03"]

    },
    {
        Title: "second title",
        Listofitems: ["Item 04", "Item 05", "Item 06"]

    }
]
```

And a sample of my code clientside looks like this:

```
const [lists, setmylist] = useState([]);
const fetchFact = () => {
    fetch("http://myapi:4000/getmyList")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => setmylist(data));
}
useEffect(() => {
    fetchFact()
}, []);
return (
    <div className='container'>
        {lists.map(singleobject => {
            var test = Object.entries(singleobject);
            { console.log(test) }
            { console.log(test[0][0]) }
            <p>{test[0][0]}</p>

        })}

    </div>
);
```

If I run this I get as `{ console.log(test)}` :

```
[
  [
    "Title",
    "first title"
  ],
  [
    "Listofitems",
    [
      "Item 01",
      "Item 02",
      "Item 03"
    ]
  ]
]
```

But the  `<p>{test[0][0]}</p>`  not gets displayed. If I change

```
{lists.map(singleobject => {})}
```

to something like

```
{projects.map(singleproject => (
                <p key={hereineedauniqueid}>Just checkin</p>    
            ))}
```

`Just checkin` gets displayed 2 times just like I want but i don´t know how to acess my values from the `json/array`. Do i need to change the structure of the `json/array` or do i need to change my code?

I think I need to use the `{lists.map(singleobject => {})}` function because i want to create a Table and a `react-bootstrap/Modal` for every elment in the `json/array` and want to display the values from the `json/array` in every specific modal

Thanks for your help

Comment: In the sample you do with Just Checkin, i dont see you using the reference to `singleproject` at all.  That would allow you to loop the p tag with the correct data in it.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up ordinary JavaScript syntax with JSX syntax in this callback here:

```
.map(singleobject => {
  var test = Object.entries(singleobject);
  { console.log(test) }
  { console.log(test[0][0]) }
  <p>{test[0][0]}</p>
})}
```

The syntax of `{ expression }` is useful inside JSX when interpolating an expression into a React component (or when debugging, for side-effects). But you're not in the context of JSX here - you're in a plain JavaScript function. Your `{}`s are denoting *plain blocks*.

```
{ console.log(test) }
```

is like doing

```
if (true) {
  console.log(test)
}
```

Then, if you were in JSX, putting

```
<p>{test[0][0]}</p>
```

right next to the interpolated logs would work - but again, you're not in JSX. You'd need to return the `<p>` to see the result. But instead of doing that, if you want to show what the value contains and iterate over each entry, consider returning a `.map` over the entries of the object.

```js
const App = () => {
    const lists = [
        {
            Title: "first title",
            Listofitems: ["Item 01", "Item 02", "Item 03"]

        },
        {
            Title: "second title",
            Listofitems: ["Item 04", "Item 05", "Item 06"]

        }
    ];
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            {lists.map(singleobject => Object.entries(singleobject)
                .map(([key, value]) => (
                  <div>
                    <div>Key: {key}</div>
                    <div>Value is a: {typeof value}</div>
                  </div>
                ))
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

But because the keys are the same for each object, looping over entries seems superfluous. It'd be easier to reference the `.Title` and `Listofitems` directly.

```js
const App = () => {
    const lists = [
        {
            Title: "first title",
            Listofitems: ["Item 01", "Item 02", "Item 03"]

        },
        {
            Title: "second title",
            Listofitems: ["Item 04", "Item 05", "Item 06"]

        }
    ];
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            {lists.map(singleobject => (
              <div>
                <div>{singleobject.Title}</div>
                <div>{singleobject.Listofitems.join(', ')}</div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
     );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need to use `Object.entries` on each object. I would leave them as objects and work with their `key/value` pairs to render things to the DOM.

For instance, with your `jsonlist`:

```
let jsonlist = [
    {
        Title: "first title",
        Listofitems: ["Item 01", "Item 02", "Item 03"]

    },
    {
        Title: "second title",
        Listofitems: ["Item 04", "Item 05", "Item 06"]

    }
]
```

You can simply render the first object like this:

```
return (
    <div className='container'>
        {lists.map(singleobject => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h3>{singleobject.Title}</h3>
                    <ol>
                        {singleobject.Listofitems.map(item => {
                            return <li>{item}</li>
                        })
                    </ol>
                </div>
            )
        })}
    </div>
```

If you are going to build a component for each of the objects in your list, you can pass the information as props to the component within your `lists.map(singleobject => {})` function.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this

```
return (<p>{test[0][0]}</p>);
```

you just need to know the basics of arrow function

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to think about the problem if you break down the interface into smaller components. You know that `data` is an array of objects that you'll have to `map` over, but your `listofitems` is also an array so it makes sense that you would also `map` over those instead.

So within your container `map` over the data you get from the endpoint to produce a new list for each object (with a title and a further list of items). You can use a separate `List` component for this into which you pass the current iterated object. (You mentioned in your question that you'd like a table, but since I don't know the format of the table you want, a list is easier to produce - but the principles still stand. Replace `List` and `ListItem` with a table row component, and a table cell component).

And in your `List` component you can create an element for the title, and a list element and then - within that - map over the object's list of items using a `ListItem` component.

Note, by doing this you'll need to add a `key` attribute to the elements that you're iterating over (or React will give you a warning). So with this in mind this example refactors the data to give each object an `id`, and also creates objects for each item each with their own id too.

For example:

```
[{ id: 1, title: 'first title', items: [{ id: 1-1, value: 'Item 01' }...]
```

```js
const data=[{title:"first title",items:["Item 01","Item 02","Item 03"]},{title:"second title",items:["Item 04","Item 05","Item 06"]}];

// Create an updated dataset with ids
const updated = data.map((obj, id) => {
  obj.id = id + 1;
  obj.items = obj.items.map((item, id) => {
    return { id: `${obj.id}-${id + 1}`, value: item };
  });
  return obj;
});

// For this example passing in the data to
// the component rather than fetching it
// `map` over the array and, for each obj create
// a list with the List component
function Example({ data }) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {data.map(obj => {
        return <List key={obj.id} obj={obj} />
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

// The List component accepts an object, and 
// we can destructure the title, and items, from
// the object. We create a title, and a list element
// and then `map` again over the items array to create
// a set of list items with the ListItem component
function List({ obj }) {
  const { title, items } = obj;
  return (
    <div className="list">
      <div className="title">{title}</div>
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => {
          const { id, value } = item;
          return <ListItem key={item.id} item={value} />
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

// Accepts an item, and returns
// a list item element
function ListItem({ item }) {
  return <li>{item}</li>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={updated} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.title { text-transform: uppercase; }
ul { list-style: none; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. the modular implementation I will surely adopt